# Default email app is always on

Tags: email

Before Android 2.2, the default email app would only show notifications if it was "off". That is, if I used Advanced Task Killer to kill it.

After Android 2.2, the default email app will show notifications regardless of me killing it.

Is there a way to get the old functionality back?

I want it to always show notifications, but only when I tell it to be "on". I know that I can change the notification settings, but that's annoying and clunky.

If there is a good alternative email app that provides this functionaly and can sync with Exchange, that would work.

Answer (score 2):

In my samsung i5500 I use a 'sync shortcut' placed on the home screen.

It is a one click on/off sync. You can add the power control widget by long pressing the home screen>Add widget>Power Control

[image: Power Control]

Or there are some such one click utility in the market.

Comment: This appears to stop syncing of all programs. I was interested in an email-specific solution, but I think this will work for me as well.

Comment: After using this, I realized that this will not prevent the email app from grabbing emails and creating notifications. Boo.

Comment: Not sure if you checked this: Settings>Accounts&Sync>Check/Uncheck Auto-Sync then specifically manage each application to sync or not to sync..